# Read data from Text View Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to read data from text view and navigate to activities.

if text view data = "admin" navigate to main activity
text view data = "user"  navigate to user Activity

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and also show have you have tried so far.

Comment: I found out how to do it @AlexMamo

Comment: Good to hear that, Jash ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Yes I found the answer

```
val uid = auth.currentUser?.uid.toString()
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document(uid)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            if (it.exists()) {
                val accessLevel = it.get("isAdmin").toString()
                userAccessLevel.text = accessLevel
            }
        }
```